# Where has create/create_record gone in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have an audit monkey patch to ActiveRecord that works on all versions of Rails from 2.x to 4.0.2 but does not work with ActiveRecord 4.1.  The code for 4.0 looks like this

```
module HLLAuditStamps

    def self.included(base)

      # create/update became create_record/update_record in Rails-4.0
      base.alias_method_chain  :create_record,      :audit
      base.alias_method_chain  :update_record,      :audit

private

    def create_record_with_audit
      set_audit_attributes
      . . .
```

This works in 4.0.2 but throws this exception in 4.1.2:

undefined method `create_record' for class`ActiveRecord::Base' (NameError)

If I go into rails console in a rails-4.1.2 project and list the methods in ActivRecord::Base I see this:

```
. . .
- :count_by_sql
- :create
- :create!
- :create_with
- :current_scope
. . .
```

As the 'create' method is what was in vogue before 4.0 that was what the original audit patch used. I returned to the original from and removed the '_record' segment throughout the module.  However, that simply throws this exception:

```
undefined method `create' for class `ActiveRecord::Base' (NameError)
```

So, where did create/create_record go to in ActiveRecord 4.1 and why am I unable to reference a method that is evidently part of the that class ?

edit:  Well, it went here:

```
#rails / activerecord / lib / active_record.rb 
module ActiveRecord
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
  . . .
    autoload :Persistence
  . . .
```

So, now I just have to figure out what to do with the information.

Comment: that is why people don't monkey patch the library source

Comment: ANYone have something a little more . . . useful?

Comment: can't you achieve the same with callbacks or observers?

Comment: Probably, If I am willing to completely rewrite code that has been happily running in production for five years just to obtain the same results.  I found the reason for the problem.  Apparently it is now 'fashionable' to use autoload, since of course this is soooo much more 'efficient'.

Comment: I will will figure out how to deal with this latest idiom no doubt.

Comment: SO, I look deeper into this and evidently 'autoload' itself is under consideration for removal from Ruby 2.x, and was supposed to be gone in 2.1 (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653) and https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3036681.

Comment: SO, they wrote their own it seems.  GAWD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Does adding a :before_save to an AR model override one already added through a custom extension to AR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073646/does-adding-a-before-save-to-an-ar-model-override-one-already-added-through-a-c)

example:

```
module HLLAuditStamps
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :set_audit_attributes
  end

  private

  def set_audit_attributes
    . . .
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include HLLAuditStamps
end
```