# Does adding a :before_save to an AR model override one already added through a custom extension to AR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We use a set of custom 'magic' columns that we check for in every AR model.  If any are found then they are appropriately populated before the call to save or save!.  This is done using the following code as an initializer:

```
module HLLAuditStamps
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :set_audit_attributes
  end

  private

  def set_audit_attributes
    . . .
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include HLLAuditStamps
end
```

The question I have is: What happens to this code if we add a before_save callback to one of the models?  Do both get executed?  Does the model callback override the default one provided in the initializer?

Comment: To clarify, both the default added above and any customized before_sae callback added to a specific model will execute.  Correct?

Comment: That's correct. I believe same rules as described under ["Inheritable callback queues" in the ActiveRecord::Callbacks docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Inheritable+callback+queues) will apply. Callback macros like `before_save` "add behavior into a callback queue that is kept intact down through an inheritance hierarchy."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, both the default added above and any customized before_save callback added to a specific model will execute. . . I believe same rules as described under "Inheritable callback queues" in the ActiveRecord::Callbacks docs will apply. Callback macros like before_save "add behavior into a callback queue that is kept intact down through an inheritance hierarchy." –  Jordan

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It was my question and that comment it answered it for me.  I added the answer simply to close the question. You are entitled to your opinion.  I disagree. This is also a year old.

Comment: ...to close the question, you should accept your answer;