# Rails version migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I'm trying to upgrade my rails app from `Rails 3 to Rails 4.2`.
Seems like many changes have been incorporated and due to which i'm getting following error:-

```
Uncaught exception: undefined method `create' for class `ActiveRecord::Base'
```

Unable to figure out a fix for it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: look at the backtrace and the line number of the first file of your own code (model or controller i'd assume). and then post that line if you can't figure it out.

Comment: user_monitor.rb:6:in `alias_method'
Line is :- alias_method :create_without_user, :create

Comment: and what code is in that file at that line?

Comment: Line is :- alias_method :create_without_user, :create

Comment: neongrau any luck?

Comment: not really. maybe add the full code of user_monitor.rb to your question

Comment: there seems to be a change with that in rails 4.2 -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962480/where-has-create-create-record-gone-in-activerecord

Comment: [ActiveRecord::Base.create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) has been replaced with [ActiveRecord::Relation.create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/create)

Comment: @maxpleaner..Somehow create method od AR:Relation.create is not getting called. Any idea how to check the exact create method under Active REcord?